# Should you pass the String to each intent before it reaches the actual activity in android

Tags: java, android, string, android-intent

I have some data in Activity 1 and i want to pass that data to activity 5...
can i just call

```
intent.putExtra("Data", somedata);
```

in the first activity and fetch that in the 5th activity.... Or should i send and fetch it through all the 5 activities in order to get the data to the last activity?

Comment: you need to pass it through all activities

Comment: Yep, otherwise you need to use shared preference

Comment: As a comment, there is a bad practice to pass data through 5 activities, because intermediate activities should not known anything about first activity. You could store this data in SharedPreferences or database and pass only an ID through activity, and retrieve it on 5th activity.

Comment: If your data is not huge, You can declare it static global variable with public access and use it in activity 5. Not a good practice but you can do so.

Comment: @hasan_shaikh it is never recommended, it will create memory leaks.

Comment: @Khemraj that's why i mentioned, it is not a good practice.